# MSBuild error when building <project> unrecognized

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have installed VS2010.  I have a simple .build file which contains this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="system" default="build">
    <target name="build">
        <exec program="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe">
            <arg value="C:\System\system.build" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

When I try to build the project by typing `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe system.build`, I received this error.

> C:\System\system.build(2,1): error MSB4068: The element  is unrecognized, or not supported in this context.

I'm interested in recommendations or suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it doesn't work is you've written the msbuild file almost exactly like you'd write ant/nant. Yes the Project is missing the xmlns tag but every other element is also incorrect.  In MSbuild The first letter is always in capitals - Project and nor project. The same goes for all the elements. 
Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project name="system" default="build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="build">
        <MSBuild Project="C:\System\system.build"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to read your question after you post (the sample was missing which is why you got no quick answers)

You're missing the `xmlns` on the project node - see a csproj for the required ns bit.

Also, it normally doesn't make much sense to run msbuild from within msbuild as you've done, but then you knew that! (There's an `MsBuild` task too, which is generally what you want if you want to nest invocations)